# Convert from Excel to CSV via asp.net (C#) under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have simple procedure for converting xlsx to csv.

```
public static void ConvertExcelToCsv(string source, string destination, int sheetNumber = 1)
{

    if (File.Exists(destination)) File.Delete(destination);

    Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();

    xl.DisplayAlerts = false;
    Excel.Workbook workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(source);
    // workbook.Close(true);
    workbook.SaveAs(destination, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    if (workbook != null)
    {
        workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        xl.Workbooks.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
    }


    xl.Quit();
    GC.Collect();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xl);
}
```

Everything works fine on my local machine and also local IIS. But after uploading onto web server seems to don't work. Everything what it does is processing about 3 mins and then time out.

I also allowed permissions in Component

`Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application -> IIS_IUSRS`

and also created Desktop folders

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\`

and also in 32bit :-)

So right now, I have no idea, why it doesn't work. Do you have similar experience with this or can you provide some hint what should I do, please.

Comment: This code works by actually running Excel on a windows 'private desktop' that you can't see. Web servers often don't have Excel installed. Even if they do, running the full Excel program for a file conversion is _awful_ for performance.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error that you receive?  Check your IIS logs and the Application event log for specific errors.

A couple things to check for:

1. Make sure Enable 32-bit applications is set to True for your app pool
2. If you have not installed Excel on your web server you need to copy the Interop assemblies when you publish your site.  To do this set Copy Local to True for the reference to the Interop.
3. Ensure your app has the appropriate permissions to the path referred to by `source` and `destination`

Comment: Yes, I have office 2013 on that web server and error message is very weird for me:

2016-03-30 15:08:57 W3SVC5 C1W13622 15.57.47.152 POST /SecondForm.aspx - 84 - 15.87.165.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/49.0.2623.87+Safari/537.36 - http://c1w13622.itcs.hpicorp.net:84/SecondForm.aspx 500 64 0 5361049 126176

Comment: When I try it from Visual Studio what I got on web server, everything works fine...

Comment: I'm very new in IIS field so please, could you explain me your point no 1, maybe step by step :-)

Comment: Ok, that's just IIS logging a 500 (Internal Error) response.  You'll need to get the real exception.  Look in the Application event log or enable remote debugging messages temporarily to get the exception.  See this link for steps to Enable 32-bit for your app pool: https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis-7-dedicated-vps.aspx

Comment: I found another in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

2016-03-30 11:27:07 15.87.165.14 52925 15.57.47.152 84 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -

Comment: That 2nd log msg is just IIS logging a timeout, but is not necessarily related to the error in question.  These log msgs can happen IIS closes a connection after X seconds of client inactivity.  It _could_ be from your request, but you'd have to cross-check it.